# i am trying to build a multiple user website in asp.net mvc but whenever i login in from diffrent computers my users get mixedup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am working on a Asp.net Mvc app where at login i make a session

```
Session["user"]="Amir";
```

and same like that at the time of registration.the problem is that when today i deploy the site on window hosting ,i use 2 laptops and login with diffrent account and then i see that user 1 is getting data of user 2 and user 2 has the data of user 1 and mostly the all the users have the data of th newly login Person.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Users", new { username = Session["user"] })"></a>
```

in my whole app i am using users session for diffrent purposese just like imagine that there are 3 users when i logout the user 2 the user 3's session remove or both 3's session remove i am so confuse may be my question don't make sense ,i have delpoy it on the server with the domain www.musayd.com
you can use these credentials to login and check 1st user(03461144220,123) 2nd user(03212999987,123) and Here is the Code where is am removing the session of user

```
 public ActionResult Logout(string username)
    {
        Session.Remove("user");
        Session.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

Like there

```
public ActionResult MyAcceptedBids(string username)
    {

            User users = (from a in db.Users where a.UserName.Equals(user) select a).FirstOrDefault(); ;
            ViewBag.namee = users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName;
            ViewBag.tag = users.TagLine;
            ViewBag.image = users.Photo;

        IList<Bids> bids = (from a in db.Bids where a.buiderusername.Equals(username) && a.status.Equals("Done") select a).ToList();


        return View(bids);

    }
```

and to trigger this i am using

```
 <li><a href="@Url.Action("MyAcceptedBids", "Users", new { username = Session["user"] })">My Accepted Bids</a></li>
```

Please Guide me